# Windows 7 x64 running a x86 .NET app will throw Out of memory unless I do GC.Collect

Tags: .net, windows-7, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have found the solution but the behavior is quite worrying and thought I ask here if anyone else seen it too.

Basically, the same binary which has been pinned to be built in x86 (will explain why below) running in x64 Windows 7 will leak unless I force a GC.Collect()

To explain:

1. The application does a lot of bitmap rendering (>60 per/sec)
2. There is an external C++ dll (managed C++)
3. There are two threads (worker and ui)
4. There is UI refreshing (stats)
5. This behavior happens only on this machine, Windows 7 x86 runs it fine.

The application will grow to over 1.5G and eventually throw an Out Of Memory exception. The faster (1) works the faster the exception.

For those ready to shoot (2) for causing the leak, I did test removing it and the leak remained **plus** the memory gets released fine if I do GC.Collect(), which in my books is a .NET issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid, we can't say much without any code, which most likely is not possible. Try to remove parts of the bitmap rendering and try to identify which part causes the leak and post that part. It might help us helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for what is worth, here is my catch.

I have seen **exactly the same issue you are experiencing**. It was back in .NET 2.0 but I was working with big images and although *I would dispose the images*, the memory consumption would go up - until I manually call `GC.Collect()`.

What else was similar? Hosting! My application was an unmanaged EXE and that would use `COM` to create a an object which was a .NET class exposed to `COM`. This would cause the unmanaged EXE to host the CLR.

On Windows X64, X32 apps will be loaded in **WOW** (windows on windows) mode which is a similar hosting which I believe can **exhibit similar issues**. It seems `GC` cannot fully understand the memory consumption when it is in a hosted environment.

Comment: Very interesting, although I don't think it is my case (forced Disposal seems to work)... I will keep in-mind either way. Thank you.

Comment: `Dispose()` did not work in mine as well. Memory would just go up with dispose as well.

Comment: I assume you mean Dispose **did** work and I think you are right... ! Dispose helps but the real problem is the fact that GC doesn't collect in the first place.

Comment: yes, exactly. I have not bothered to report it yet since I moved to another company but your case sounds interesting.

Comment: That last paragraph needs to go.  The premise of "I don't know what's going on, must be a bug in Windows" is *very* unhelpful.  It makes users stop looking for the real problem.  And it is nonsense, wow64 is rock solid.

Comment: @Hans, I said `It seems` which expresses the fact that it is my personal view. This is just an observation, what is wrong with it? Also who said `a bug in Windows`? I said hosting a CLR can cause issues in GC as I witnessed one myself.

Comment: It sounds like you may have experienced the same symptom, but from your description the actual problem sounds totally unrelated. I don't see any similarity between COM Interop and WOW64, and I'd say your problem was most likely due to an application bug - there's no evidence that hosting a CLR can cause issues in GC.

Comment: @Joe, no it was not an application bug. I stripped the code down to just loading images and disposing them - it was causing the memory leaks. I have made it absolutely clear that this is just an observation and a hunch, I have started by `OK, for what is worth, here is my catch.`... the symptoms are the same. This actually made me decide to reproduce the issue and report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly disposing your bitmaps - and all other disposable resources including GDI+ objects?

```
using(Bitmap bitmap = ...)
{
    ... do your stuff
}
```

You need to look at your application to find the problem - clearly 1.5GB is excessive for a 32-bit app.  The fact that you are getting different behaviour on different machines with different OS doesn't mean you should blame the OS.

Comment: No I am not blaming the OS... however I know that MS states somewhere that the x64 garbage collector runs in less-regular circles than the x86.

Comment: I believe this was the issue. It appears that forcing a Dispose() method call for each bitmap created has "flattened" the memory usage graph... I don't mean to be critical but I would say this **is** an issue/bug with the framework as it is not triggering the expected clean-up behavior

Comment: @George: "I would say this is an issue/bug with the framework" - I disagree.  Applications are expected to call IDisposable.Dispose on all types that implement IDisposable.  The fact that you can get away without doing it in some circumstances doesn't change the fact that it's your responsibility to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could try not to rely on the garbage collector as much. If you rewrite your draw code to clean up unused resources, you probably won't run into the scenario described.

[Image.Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z.aspx)

> Note Always call Dispose before you
>   release your last reference to the
>   Image. Otherwise, the resources it is
>   using will not be freed until the
>   garbage collector calls the Image
>   object's Finalize method.

Comment: Yeap, so why isn't the collector running? Forcing the collection worked

Answer (score 0):

You have to .Dispose() of your bitmaps when you stop using them.
The GC will eventually collect this memory (when it runs the finalizer) even if you don't explicitly call .Dispose() - but the GC is not a magic cure for over-allocating memory, if you do it faster then the GC can collect them, using resources the GC cant control directly (unmanaged resources are exactly that) - then the GC mechanism can't help you.

By calling GC.Collect(0) you are forcing the GC to process the object tree and call all the finalizers, if you don't call it then the GC runs when it thinks it's time, and by then it's too late (due to the high allocation rate).

Comment: It sounds about right ... so this is by design? I mean, throw an out of memory exception before even trying to get GC to collect?!

Comment: Correction: I don't think its the bitmap disposing (will check) cause memory would overflow a lot faster than it currently does (takes a good few minutes at peak rate) - considering average image size of about 200x200 pixels

Comment: The GC attempts to run every once in a while, and when the application reaches the memory limit, the GC will start running more and more cycles. you'll notice that CPU consumption spikes when memory approaches around 1.5 gig.
As for the bitmap size - each image should take up (avg) 200x200x4 bytes =~160k. so it's not that much, but it really depends on what you do with them - i.e. if you very frequently lose scope of the images and reallocate them (say in every render phase) - that may require a lot of memory. it would help to know what you're doing actually :)

Comment: What's missing from my GC comment before is that the finalizer runs on a special thread, this thread cannot cleanup COM STA objects (like the interop Image in question). [it MUST run on the UI thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx), if the UI thread is busy, say allocating more images - this memory cannot be released and thus you'll run out of memory.